# Asio: usage of self shared pointer in the examples

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

Looking through the examples of the Asio library, [this one for example](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/src/examples/cpp14/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) (for instance, line 37), I see that sometimes they create a shared pointer from this (they name it self), and capture it in a lambda where they call some asio functions, but I don't understand what the purpose of it. I don't even see it used.

So, why do they do this?

---

*Relevant Code:*

..in the server class... (where a session is created)

```
if (!ec)
{
    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
}
```

... `session::start()` member method:

```
void start()
  {
    do_read();
  }
```

... `session::do_read()` member method (where my point of interest is):

```
void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());                    // <<< ---WHY THIS??????
    socket_.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(length);
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of [`std::enable_shared_from_this<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) is to create an extra `std::shared_ptr` from the [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) handle that owns the object calling [`shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) member function.

---

```
if (!ec)
{
     std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
}
```

The above *-^^^-* is where the [line](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/src/examples/cpp14/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp#L84) that creates a `session`. And as you can see, the `std::shared_ptr` that is returned by `std::make_shared` will be destroyed at the `;`, which should also destroy the `session` created...

But because [`start()`](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/src/examples/cpp14/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp#L29) method calls [`do_read()`](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/src/examples/cpp14/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp#L35) which is defined as...

```
void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(length);
          }
        });
  }
```

That `self` increases the `shared_ptr` reference count. so the destruction of the [original `shared_ptr`](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/src/examples/cpp14/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp#L84) created will not destroy the object, rather, it will leave self as the reference to the created object.

---

Also know that a Lambda can outlive its caller... `boost::asio::async_write` is an asynchronous method that returns immediately after copying it's arguments. The passed lambda may not execute before you reach the *end of life* of your `session`. Hence without the additional `std::shared_ptr` created by `shared_from_this`, the destructor will run. That additional `shared_ptr` prevents the destructor of `session` from running, until the lambda function is called and it's arguments are destructed.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda's to which you refer are capturing state (for example the this pointer) from the class object and they need to ensure the object is still alive when they access the state. Remember those lambdas are being called asynchronously, for example when there is data ready to read. The function that instantiated the class initially and the async lambdas thus all share ownership of the class instance.

Have you read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), if not it might be helpful?